# Why a pointer into a string is displayed backwards when converted to hexidecimal

Tags: c

When i run the piece of code specified below with ./add 10 10

I expect output to be:  **64 64 00 31** (hexidecmal values for d d \0 1)

Instead I get:  **31 00 64 64** . What is the reason behind that?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int *iptr =(int *)&(argv[1][1]);
    printf("%x ",iptr[-1]);
```

Comment: because you're running on a little-endian machine?  The code has undefined behavior, so might do just about anything.

Comment: I am using compiler on UNIX. I have never heard of "little-endian machine" before... I guess I need to read more on that topic but assuming it was, are they reading from left to right?

Comment: @Cris Why would you say that, i think it is pretty clear that Tim just wants to know how to add up two ints in the stdargs.
Tim, what you're looking for is `atoi(char*)` because argv contains string representations of the two ints.

Comment: @David Thanks for the answer but I am trying to understand the behavior of the code. I would never write code similar to the one I asked about but i want to understand the behavior of the code because it is an exam question... I understand that iptr[-1] is pointing to the first "d" in the string. The question is: What is the value(hexidecimal representation) stored in iptr[-1].

Comment: Ah ok sorry,  i misunderstood, but yea it has to do with how processors handle integers. It basically all goes back to the us using the arabic number system, which goes right to left and us people getting confused. But it differs per machine what order the bytes go in an integer. I don't have time now to write an answer, but if you google for `endianness` you'll find some good (confusing) reads .

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank you! :)

Comment: When posting about a run time problem, always post code that cleanly compiles.  The posted code is not even a complete function, much less a compilable program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)" of a CPU is a property of the physical architecture of the CPU of a computer.

Intel x86 compatible CPUs are little endian, which means that when storing a multi-byte integer in memory, the **least** significant byte is stored in the **lower** memory address.  This seems "backwards" to a human's typical way of thinking about numbers.  If you were to view a hex dump of the 32-bit integer **0xaabbccdd** from little endian machine then you's see it from left to right as `ddccbbaa`.

On big endian machines (Sun Sparc for instance) the same hex dump would contain `aabbccdd` which seems more intuitive to most people.

The reason that little endianness exists is primarily down to the way that the architecture is implemented in CPU manufacture.  That's beyond the scope of this question.

Normally a programmer doesn't have to think about endianness unless they are doing peculiar, esoteric things.  Well written C code can usually be compiled for big or little endian machines without having to take this difference into account, as the compiler knows how to cope with it itself.

`char` on the other hand is a single byte long and therefore it is represented left-to-right on all CPUs, regardless of endianness.

Edit: here's a short program to tell you the endianness of any computer you run it on...

Compile this with:   **gcc -pedantic -std=c99 main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
  uint8_t i[4]  = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD};

  //deliberately casting this to a void* because we're interested in the hardware
  //storage order of the individual bytes...
  uint32_t* ptr = (void*) &i[0];

  switch(*ptr)
  {
    case 0xAABBCCDD:
      printf("BIG endian.");
      break;

    case 0xDDCCBBAA:
      printf("LITTLE endian.");
      break;

    case 0xBBAADDCC:
      printf("MIDDLE endian (am I a PDP-11?).");
      break;

    default:
      printf("WARNING -- unknown endianness!");
      break;
  }

  printf("  0x%08X\n", *ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Middle endianness also exists, but we won't mention that :)